# Get Abstract Syntax tree for Java method using JDT Eclipse

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm working on a project that must use Eclipse JDT for parsing java methods and generating Abstract Syntax tree for them
I wrote the following code :

```
String method ="\n"+
    "   public void sayHello() {\n"+
    "   System.out.println(\"Hello \"+name+\"!\");\n"+
    "   }\n";
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setSource(method.toCharArray());
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);
```

This snippet just creates AST, but I get stuck!!
I'd like to visit AST of any java method and print its path.
Can I get print AST for java Method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse AST (as most AST actually) exploit the visitor pattern extensively.

So from the point you are, all you have to do is to instantiate a visitor, and make it visit the compilation unit. It will then automatically navigate fields, methods, annotations...

For your specific need, I think you can start with the following code:

```
unit.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

    @Override
    public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
        Type ownerTypeNode = (Type) node.getParent();
        System.out.println("Found method " + node.getName().getFullyQualifiedName() " + " in type " + ownerTypeNode.getName().getFullyQualifiedName());
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't test right now, but I believe that your problem may be that the sample code you are trying to parse does not include a type declaration; Eclipse's parser is relatively forgiving, but the exact behaviour is sometime hard to predict when the input is not perfectly valid. Try adding `public class xxx { ... }` around your sample code.

Comment: Alternatively, I think that setting the parser's kind to `K_CLASS_BODY_DECLARATIONS` would make it assume that it is inside a type definition, so you wouldn't need to add the type definition around your sample code.

Comment: I post Answer with an image .https://stackoverflow.com/a/52596635/4555727

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by this image... https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuJCi.png  Do you want to also produce an image that looks like the image you provided? Or do you want to produce text where information follow some formal presentation? If so, can you provide an example of what would be a correctly formated tect?

Comment: sir, How can I contact with you for some Questions related in this topic

Comment: There would be SO's chats, but I'm afraid that you can't use this at present as it require a minimum of 20 reputation points to be able to write there... Anyway, I may have more appropriate suggestions, though I first need to get a better understanding of your objective.... Si do you want to produce an image or a strictly formatted text?

Comment: Oh, My problem has been solved 
I'm able now to generate AST for java  method 
many thanks @ jwatkins

Comment: You are welcome. May I suggest then that you close the question if it has been resolved. You may do so by flagging as "accepted" the answer that best helped you. Hopefully, this might help other people at a later time facing similar questions.

Comment: Many thanx sir for helping...
I have another question .. 
for the code found at: 
         https://stackoverflow.com/a/52596635/4555727
I get AST for this as string:
          MethodDeclaration SimpleType SimpleName String SimpleName extractFor SingleVariableDeclaration SimpleType SimpleName Integer SimpleName id Block ExpressionStatement MethodInvocation SimpleName LOG SimpleName debug SimpleName "Extracting method with ID:{}" SimpleName id ReturnStatement MethodInvocation SimpleName requests SimpleName remove SimpleName id 
How can I represent this as Tree that know each child's node ?